# The product code is incorrect

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with the colissimo module I cannot print my parcel label because I have the following error The product code is incorrect but when I go to the product catalog my product does exist.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can update this module, for me it works.